# What is the best data structure for one to many relation on Django?

Tags: python, django, data-structures

For instance, let's suppose we have a webapp with `Pizza` and `Topping`s.

One pizza can have many toppings but a topping cannot have many pizzas, which seems logical so far.

I'm using a structure like this one below but I am not sure wether I should use `ManyToMany` Field or `ForeignKey` since OneToMany doesn't exist on Django.

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.order_id

class Topping(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    custom_topping_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #if a pizza is deleted, delete its toppings.

    def __str__(self):
        return self.topping_name
```

If I'm doing this right, should I access a pizza and all its toppings like this ?

```
pizzas = Pizza.topping_set.filter(order_id=my_order_id)
```

Is there a better way or is it optimal to keep it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A topping *can* have many pizzas. A topping is not specific to a particular pizza - pepperoni can be on as many pizzas as you like, and you don't want a separate instance of Topping with name "pepperoni" for each pizza it is on. So many-to-many is the appropriate structure here.

If you did have a ForeignKey though, it is more idiomatic to access the toppings through the pizza itself:

```
my_pizza = Pizza.objects.get(order_id=order_id)
toppings = my_pizza.topping_set.all()
```

Comment: (just to have a better understanding of ForeignKey). In case toppings are defined and doesn't change its value, I understand a topping can have many pizzas, but let's suppose we have companies and workers, and we set this rule where a worker cannot be in many companies, would it be better to use ForeignKey?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what ForeignKey is for; a worker would have a field `company = models.ForeignKey(Company)`,

Answer (score 0):

Okay i will make it clear (as i think)

What is the best data structure for one to many relation on Django?

1-n : `ForeignKey`

Why?

1. It is about query style. the model Pizza will have n Topping relate to it right?

`pizza1 = Pizza.Objects.get(pk=1)`

```
topping_for_pizza1 = Topping.Objects.filter(pizza=pizza1)
```

In this way, we have topping_for_pizza1.pizza will return the pizza object.
and query _set will work also.

`ManytoMany` is 2 ways relationship it mean 2 FK. That all i think about it.

Hope it help, use FK pls